# Android album art path reload

Tags: java, android

I am displaying album art into an ImageView and it's working fine.If I delete the album art files from **data/com.android.providers.media/albumthumbs**.How do I refresh this folder through the code. Any one please let me know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                           Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```